# How to import data from a Google Cloud database into Matlab?

Tags: matlab, google-cloud-platform

From Matlab I want to import all the data that is found in a database that is hosted on Google Cloud (Google Cloud SQL) but I don't know if a driver is needed or the default software allows connection to a Google Cloud database. Which are the steps to follow? Can I use a connector that is already in Matlab?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend exporting your data to a CSV file in your Google Cloud SQL first by following this [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv).

Then you can use the `Matlab` [importtool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool.html) to import the CSV file or you can check this [post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/72545-how-to-import-csv-file-in-matlab#:%7E:text=To%20import%20data%20from%20a,number%20of%20lines%20to%20skip.) for other ways to import it into your Matlab project.