# Is there a way of retrieving data from a Google Cloud Database from MATLAB programmatically?

Tags: matlab, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a standalone MATLAB application which is going to be distributed to 2 different users. I would like each instance of my application to connect to Google Cloud Database (MySQL), retrieve some data, manipulate it in the user's local computer and then send the data back to be stored in Google Cloud Database.

Is there way of connecting MATLAB directly to Google Cloud Database programmatically? (e.g. WITHOUT exporting a .csv file from the database manually first)

Thanks for any help.

Obviously, I tried exporting the data manually as a .csv file and it works. Just looking for a way of automating this process from within MATLAB. Therefore, previous answers regarding the method of exporting a CSV first does not apply to me.

Comment: This is a duplicate question from 2 years ago, except the only answer is suggesting doing exactly what you don't want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582384/how-to-import-data-from-a-google-cloud-database-into-matlab... Looks like there's a FileExchange utility which might help: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/99234-matlab-google-cloud-storage

Comment: Yep, saw that utility but had some problems trying to make it work. Anytime something outside native Matlab functions are used in the compiler to make a standalone application, problems arise. I will try a little more and let you know.